# Pthread I/O buffers: Why doese it print a redundant line?

Tags: c, pthreads, buffer

```
#include "apue.h"                                                               
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>


void* fun(void *arg)
{
    printf("%lu: I'm alive\n", pthread_self());
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **v)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, fun, NULL);
    printf("%lu: I'm dead\n", pthread_self());

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
3075692224: I'm dead
3075689280: I'm alive
3075689280: I'm alive

$ ./a.out
3076470464: I'm dead
```

Somtimes, it prints a line. 
I think
one line: `3076470464: I'm dead`
or 
two lines:

```
3075692224: I'm dead
3075689280: I'm alive
```

should be rigjt.
Beacause I don't use `pthread_join`but why it could print three lines;

Comment: Exit your threads correctly and your output should be fine. Currently the code produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Sometimes it is much easy to fix a problem than to understand why it happend just like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You observer the mysteries of unprotected concurrent access to shared resources, that is the buffered `stdout` in this case.

Use a mutex to protect `stdout` against concurrent access, and everything will work as expected: One `printf()` statement will match one printed line.

However your program risks that main() exits before the thread ended, and with this the ending program might destroy the thread at a random position.